# Select all items in a specific folder and move them to another folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

How do I select all Mails in the Deleted Items folder of a shared account (not my personal account) and then move them to a different folder not called "Deleted Items". For now, let's call the destination folder "Old Emails".

Here is what I have written so far:

```
'Macro for pseudo-archiving
Sub PseudoArchive()
On Error Resume Next

Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Messages As Selection
Dim Msg As MailItem

Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("sharedemail@website.com")
Set sourceFolder = objFolder.Folders("Deleted Items")

'Define path to the target folder
Set destinationFolder = ns.Folders("sharedemail@website.com").Folders("Old Emails")

'Move emails in sourceFolder to destinationFolder
For Each Msg In sourceFolder
    Msg.Move destinationFolder
Next

Set objNamespace = Nothing
Set sourceFolder = Nothing
Set Messages = Nothing
Set Msg = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am stuck on how to get the macro to select all items in the `sourceFolder` so it can then move them to the `destinationFolder`. I prefer not to manually select the emails in the folder before running the macro.

If anyone can provide assistance, that would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that should help.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olFol As Outlook.Folder, olDestFol As Outlook.Folder
Dim olItem As Object
Dim i as Long, j as Long
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("mailboxnamehere").Folders("Deleted Items")
Set olDestFol = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders("mailboxnamehere").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Deleted Items") ' Destination Folder
Do Until olFol.Items.Count = 0
    olFol.Items(1).Move olDestFolder
Loop
```

Comment: You should not modify the collection in a "for each" loop. Use a down loop from Count down to 1.

Comment: Why do you reference the shared mailbox Inbox folder in the olDestFol assignment by not the olFol assignment?

Comment: Because this was copied from a code snippet I prepared in another answer about a shared mailbox, but it would be your email address in this case.

Comment: You might also want to avoid using multipel dot notation - cache the Items collection before entering the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it, try the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub PseudoArchive()
    Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim destinationFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("sharedemail@website.com").Folders("Deleted Items")
    Set destinationFolder = objNamespace.Folders("sharedemail@website.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Old Emails")
    Set Items = sourceFolder.Items

    'Move emails in sourceFolder to destinationFolder
    Msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & sourceFolder.Name & ", Move?"

    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Set Item = Items.Item(i)
            DoEvents
            Item.Move destinationFolder
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```